# Can I use SAP UI5 mockserver without having a oData model

Tags: jquery, mocking, sapui5, mockserver

Backend : Jersey backend
Frontend : SAPUI5 application with a JSON model

I use jQuery.ajax() calls to make requests to the backend. I would like to mock these requests and load mock data to do a quick POC.

The Mockserver provided by SapUI5 seems to work with only oData model. can it be used with json models? https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/bae9d90d2e9c4206889368f04edab508.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JSon models you don't need the mockServer actually.
In the Component.js try to load your JSon model as below

```
var oModel = new JSONModel(uritojson);
this.setModel(oModel);
```

uritojson is the link to your mock file

Ivan

Comment: Thanks for the response. Okay, well I could do this or use oModel.loadData(uritojson) I suppose.  Right now on view load (on init )I am doing a jquery GET  to the backend to load the initial data. If I load the model as a part of component.js how do I 'switch' between the real and actual calls??   I am sorry If I sound confused, I am new to sapui5 and trying to learn by building an app.

Comment: @daredadevil did you find a solution ? I have a similar question. Can you check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111069/how-to-setup-mockserver-and-mockdata-for-xsjs-service

Comment: @loki no I didn't find a way. For the mock server packaged with SapUI5, you're out of luck if you're not working with odata. :(. someone suggested using express js for mocking sometime ago, maybe it's worth looking into it. sorry I couldn't help more

Comment: @daredadevil okay my teammate suggested a way of creating a backend.js file consisting mockdata which was being recieved from the services.
Then refer this files through indextest.html and refer the main backend.js consisting of real services through index.html.
For this I used sap.ui.getResourcePath() or something like this function I donot remember exactly.
Thank you very much for the reply  anyways :D